# Genrics Value Checking Error

Tags: c#, console

This Code is Getting Error at line 11 and 13,Error Message is Error "Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'int'"
How can I check Values and print it in other way

```
class absval<T>
{
    private T _no;
    public void storeval(T x)
    {
        this._no = x;
    }
    public T getval()
    {
        if(this._no<0)
        {
        return (this._no*-1);
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        absval<int> a1 = new absval<int>();
        absval<double> a2 = new absval<double>();
        a1.storeval(-20);
        a2.storeval(-20.4);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}",a1.getval(),a2.getval());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not in danger of conversion errors with high precision numbers, you could use the numbers IConvertible implementation to get a generic approach. It looks cleaner than implementing a lot if and elses, although the former would probably be more efficient on micro level.

```
    public T getval()
    {
        if(_no is IConvertible) //could also be put in the generic constraint for <T>
        {
            //use decimal for the largest precision, 
            var dec = Convert.ToDecimal(_no); //will throw an exception if not numeric
            if (dec < 0) 
            {
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(-dec, typeof(T));
            }
        }
        return _no;        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `_no` is of type `T` where `T` is not constrained in any sense, so it can be a `string`, a `Button` or a `double`.

The compiler does not know how you are using the class, and it cannot guarantee that the  line `_no < 0` will make sense for the actual type put in the `T` (e.g., what should `"Hello" < 0` do?), so it issues a compile error.

That said, C# does not have a generic constraint to a numeric type, so there is no simple way to do what you want to do (make a single `absval` method for all numeric types). Even if you look at the implementation of the static `Math.Abs` method, you will see that it has specific overloads for each and every one of the numeric types.